# Quartz.Net "remembering" job types that no longer exist

Tags: asp.net, quartz-scheduler, scheduler, quartz.net

Using Quartz.Net 2.3.3 with an ADO data store for my ASP.NET MVC application.

Periodically I get the .NET error

> "Could not load type *type_name*..."

where *type_name* is the name of a Quartz job class I defined (inherited from IJob).  However, *type_name* was a job class that I had commented out many deployments ago.

In short, it seems that Quartz is remembering ghost job types that no longer exist in my code.

After I get an error like this I query my Quartz tables and sure enough there are references to these job types which do not exist.  If I empty the tables (is there something else I need to do aside from clearing out the tables?), the situation is cleared up for a bit...until it happens again.

As I indicated earlier, all code that either defined or referenced *type_name* has been commented out, and each time I compile and deploy I erase all files at the destination to ensure I've got no rogue assemblies hanging around.

There is no other source for jobs for job info aside from my executing code; for example, there's no quartz configuration file that defines the *type_name* job that's getting pulled in.

How would quartz remember these non-existent jobs even after I erase all Quartz tables?

Comment: One thing that comes to my mind is that if you have XML file that has the types defined or a rogue server in clustered environment that could be adding these. If database is cleared (rows deleted for jobs and associated triggers) this definitely should not be happening.

Comment: @marko - Totally agree. Found nothing. Did full text search of disk in fact! And the Quartz scheduler actually runs in process in the asp.net app and it's the only instance.